# How can I remove a tick I cannot reach and no one is around to help?

Tags: wild-camping, wilderness, ticks, solo-hiking, solo-backpacking

How can you remove a tick on your back if you cannot reach it with your hand and you have no one to assist you?

Comment: When I was in that situation, I had to walk two hours in pouring rain to the next doctor. I don't think there's anything you can do about it except look for help.

Comment: My doc says that antibiotic is not needed if the tick has been attached for less than 36 hours.    So you have nearly 36 hours to find someone to help, assuming you found the tick quickly.  It looks like @PMF could have waited until it stopped raining.

Comment: @ab2 Except that I did not know how long the tick had been there when I found it. As a matter of fact, I did get the typical indications of borreliosis a few days later.

Comment: I find it hard to believe every time one gets a tick bite that they have to run to a dr. and get a shot or have it removed. First of all, people who live and work in the country get bit by them on a weekly if not daily basis, despite repellents, tucked in clothes and all those other feel good precautions that you read online and the CDC tells you to do. That is not going to happen in real life. People can't hop in a car drive 60 miles to see a dr. or get a shot or be tested everytime they get bit. They might as well rent an apartment next to the medical facility and live nearby.

Comment: And the question is. "How to DIY when you are in a situation without doctors, or other people around to help?" Lets say your stranded on an island and you have a tick on your back you cannot possibley reach. How do you remove it? Or if you cannot, then maybe next best thing, .. how to kill it?

Comment: Russ:  See [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/28216/is-this-a-well-known-way-to-kill-ticks-that-are-out-of-reach-on-your-body)